# What could be an example of a convex compact set in $\mathcal{R}^2$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, education

I know what are the conditions for a set to be convex and compact but can't imagine any graphical representation of that, could give some example?

I was thinking in an ellipse, since its bounded.

Comment: A closed disk, a closed ellipse, a closed rectangle.

Comment: $\{(0,0)\}$ is compact and convex.